# How can I declare an interpolated string based on a negative lookahead?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I will be parsing my code to an AST and looking for imports. The imports I am looking for will be ones that *do not* include `-v3` at the end of them.

```
@ui/components                  <- this will match
@ui/components/forms/field      <- this will match
@ui/components-v3               <- this should not match
@ui/components-v3/forms/field   <- this should not match
```

Now what I want to do is create a typeguard which will look at these import declarations and assert that they are indeed of this form, then return that as an interpolated string. e.g.,

```js
function isDeprecatedComponentLibraryImport(importPath: string): importPath is `@ui/components${string}`;
```

The problem I am running into here is that I want the *inverse* of this; I want it to return that the string in question matches `@ui/components${string}` and *not* `@ui/components-v3${string}`

I could make a `complement` function that returns the inverse but that's not ideal because that will just say that the string is definitely not `@ui/components-v3${string}`, not that it *is* `@ui/components${string}`

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the type

```
'@ui/components' | `@ui/components/${string}`
```

This will not just exclude `components-v3` but also all other folder names except `components`.